# What do the gray/silver crown icons mean in Super Mario Galaxy 2?

Tags: nintendo-wii, super-mario-galaxy-2

In *Super Mario Galaxy 2* for the Nintendo Wii, when choosing a galaxy to go to, some galaxies have a gray (or maybe silver is a better description) crown-like icon next to them. I can't tell if this is indicating that I have already received a silver crown, or if it's a grayed-out version of a colored crown (gold maybe?) which I have not yet received.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about and if so, what do these crown icons signify? I'll try to find a picture if nobody understands what I'm talking about...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The silver crown means you have collected every star and the comet medal in a particular galaxy. After getting 120 stars, more things to collect unlock in each galaxy. When you collect all of those the silver crown becomes a gold crown.

To clarify, it has nothing to do with how many coins you get.

Comment: Side Note: Some stars are not initially available, so you may not be able to get a silver star the first time through a stage.

Answer (score 3):

The gray crown means you have gotten everything you can get (all stars and the comet coin) in a Galaxy prior to getting 120 stars. Later on, after you have gotten 120 stars, there are additional things to do in each Galaxy - completing all of those will get you a gold crown.

It's a quick indicator of whether you have completed a Galaxy. If you don't see a crown, you need to go back!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The gray crowns include getting all coins, too? I can't believe I did that, but maybe I'm more skilled than I thought :-)

Comment: Oops, by "coins" I meant the comet coins. Not actually every coin in the level. That would be nuts!

Answer (score 0):

The Silver crown shows you have collected all regular stars in the particular Galaxy you have your crown in. If you get all the green stars in the same Galaxy this turns into a Golden crown. This has nothing to do with the Coins you collect in the Galaxy.

Comment: This does not add any relevant information that the currently accepted answer does not already state. Please keep in mind that duplicate answrs are frowned upon here and maybe subject to deletion.